# Magura Vyron dropper seatpost internal shaft can be easily twisted

Tags: mountain-bike, seatpost, dropper

I had a very light crash (in fact just rode into a bush) after which I noticed I twisted magura vyron seat post. Apparently my seat post clamp was too tight.. Now it can be twisted when some force is applied which seems to be dangerous, of course. Is there something I can do myself or I have to send it to service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar happened to me a couple of years ago, after my bicycle was transported by a freight company for several thousands of kilometers, and the Vyron seatpost apparently had received a couple of sideways strikes.

You do not provide details about which seatpost's parts are loose. I'd guess it is the internal movable shaft that now rotates against the external piece. It seems (at least it was so in my case) that the shaft of the seatpost is threaded into something inside. It means you can thread it back to be tight by rotating the shaft clockwise (looking from the top). Be careful to not unscrew it all the way out of course, it should get tighter quite soon after you start rotating it.

Comment: Yeah, that's the part. Now I know how to call it:D. Kinda afraid I might "screw" something but I'll try. The sounds coming from it while rotating are not conforming though and the symbol is just in the middle as if indicating the right position already - but I'll see what I can do - thank you!

Comment: @Greg You are likely to need to reposition the whole seatpost unit in the frame after you've tightened the inner shaft back. Do not pay too much attention to the symbols on the seatpost's collar — that collar itself can be unscrewed in order to clean the internals and to add more grease, so its position can be rotated as well.